# How to get distinct results using GORM

Tags: mysql, sql, go, go-gorm

In Go, I write a query that gives me all data but I just want to data where products.id and clients.id are distinct.
What is the simile query I can write?

```
res := find.Model(&domain.Clients{}).
    Select ("products.id product_id, products.name product_name,"+
        " clients.id id, clients.name name, clients.logo, clients.address, "+
        "clients.business_id, clients.num_of_employee, clients.email, clients.sns_link, clients.phone").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN company_interests ON company_interests.client_id = clients.id").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = company_interests.product_id").
    Where("products.id = ? ", productId).Find(&resp)
```

Comment: Is there a GroupBy function?

Comment: No , it is just a simple query .

Comment: Let me rephrase: Is GORM supporting GroupBy? If you need distinct values, then your query will ultimately need to contain a GROUP BY clause or a DISTINCT. I wonder whether `Select ("distinct products.id product_id, products.name product_name,"+
        " clients.id id, clients.name name, clients.logo, clients.address, "+
        "clients.business_id, clients.num_of_employee, clients.email, clients.sns_link, clients.phone").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN company_interests ON company_interests.client_id = clients.id")` is valid syntax in GORM.

Comment: I write exactly simile query and work fine in mysql workbench but when run this query gorm shows error


Error 3065: Expression #1 of ORDER BY clause is not in SELECT list, references column 'd2d_db.clients.created_at' which is not in SELECT list; this is incompatible with DISTINCT

Comment: Okay, then maybe with GROUP BY you will have better luck.

Comment: Apparently there is a Group function, see https://gorm.io/docs/query.html

Comment: Thanks 
Done  , it's working fine with  GROUP BY.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the solution or can you write an answer?

Comment: @LajosArpad written down the answer.

Answer (score 3):

In Go when i write "Select Distinct" then rest query , it is not valid in go. So, i got an idea to write the query using "group by". In Go "group by" syntax can be used by "GROUP" syntax . So, finally bellow query works fine for me.

```
res := find.Model(&domain.Clients{}).
    Select ("products.id product_id, products.name product_name,"+
        " clients.id id, clients.name name, clients.logo, clients.address, "+
        "clients.business_id, clients.num_of_employee, clients.email, clients.sns_link, clients.phone").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN company_interests ON company_interests.client_id = clients.id").
    Joins("LEFT JOIN products ON products.id = company_interests.product_id").
    Where("products.id = ? ", productId).
    Group("company_interests.client_id, company_interests.product_id" ).Find(&resp)
```